# Exception thrown trying to navigate between pages in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, navigation

This is the code I am using to navigate between pages in my WPF application:

```
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
        this.Content = mainMenu;
```

It works when navigating from the main menu to one of my pages, but for this "back" button, using the same code, I get the following error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot
>   add Window as a child of Visual.

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way of navigating between pages?

Comment: You don't "navigate between pages" in WPF, you open and close windows, or change their content. It sounds like you're changing the content of your first window (which is OK but unusual) and then trying to load a new window as the content of the original window, which isn't allowed. If you want to make window act like a browser, define all your pages (including the main menu) as UserControls and load them into the content of your window.

Comment: You can't set the Content property to a window.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your .xaml file:

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
            <ContentControl x:Name="ListPanel" />
 </Grid>
```

and add this to the .cs file:

```
Downaload downaload = new Downaload();
ListPanel.Content = downaload;
```